# What is wrong with this code for 'match' and regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string which is something like:

```
ABC:Something|Hello World
```

I want the data after '|' character so I am using regex for it.

```
sample_str = "ABC:Something|Hello World"
puts sample_str.match(/[^|]*$/)
```

This works on rubular and returns me "Hello World" as the output, but doesn't work in my ruby code. What am I missing here? I get `#<MatchData "">` in Ruby.

UPDATE: Nevermind. If I use the regex and do match on the string it works now. I was doing it other way round i.e. I did `(regex).match(string)` instead of `(string).match(regex)`.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Works on my machine: `sample_str.match(/[^|]*$/) # => #<MatchData "Hello World">`

Comment: My understanding was it should work on mine too. But if I do regex first and then match on the string then it works on my machine now. Am not sure what's why it's that way. Even I most of the times do string.match(regex)

Comment: this is what i get when i put it on the console `2.1.2 :013 > sample_str = "ABC:Something|Hello World"
"ABC:Something|Hello World"
2.1.2 :014 > puts sample_str.match(/[^|]*$/)
Hello World`

Comment: mods - how is this off topic and not about programming?

Comment: The close votes say it's off-topic because "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." Remember, it's a peer-moderated site so other users are making those determinations, not moderators.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this. A simple `split('|')` is a more direct path without all the hassle.

Comment: Split doesn't help me much. I also have a string which has '' after '|'. So the string is like "ABC:Something|". split('|').last on this returns me ABC:Something

Answer (score 7):

Using regex seems excessive:

```
string.split('|').last
```

Answer (score 0):

Below regex should help you.

```
^[\S\s]+?\|([\w\s]+)$
```

Dont forget to select `global` and `multiline` options.

Look at the [regex demo here](http://regex101.com/r/aG0oL5/1).